# I want to know the proper use of section tag in html5

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I inspect element and moved cursor on any particular section tag.
the section tag highlighting only top of the main parent div only with **height 0** . Not showing that actual section tag where it is like **display inline-block**.  I just want to know why it's like this. what is proper way to use section tag.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
   <section id="amenities-part">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Amenities</h2>
     <span>Lift</span> <br><span>AC</span> 
  </div>
   </section>
   <section id="services-part">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Services</h2>
     <span>Cooking</span> <br><span>Cooking</span>
  </div>
   </section>
   <section id="safety-part">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Safety</h2>
     <span>First Aid Kit</span> <br><span>Fire Extinguisher </span>
  </div>
   </section>
   <section id="local-service-part">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Local Area Service</h2>
     <span>jfh</span> <br><span>jfh</span>
  </div>
   </section>
   <section id="handler-detail-part">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <h2>Handler Detail</h2>
     <img class="img-responsive" alt="Handler-profile-picture" width="75px" src="https://www.primomedico.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Prof-Dr-Schmidli-Juerg-Spezialist-Gefaesschirurgie-Bern-Portrait_klein.jpg">
     <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
  </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Section tag has the functionality of a div, but semantically it has a purpose unlike the generic div. Sections designate/represent chapters/portions, and similar aspects of a document.

Comment: yes. But also i want to know why it's not showing full when inspect it and keep cursor on the section?

Comment: put clearfix class into the section tag

Comment: Your section tags look like they are proper and they have height. At least the ones I am inspecting atm. Each section tag is 58px high and the last one is 158px high. What do you expect to see borders?

Comment: did you tried on full page?? there not showing. :-(

Comment: It's not showing because your `div[class^="col-"]`elements are floating and your sections aren't clearfixed. See [All About Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: @noni if i used class clearfix its disturbing other element.

Comment: @jordi then in this situation what have to do.. is it okay to put same as it is?

Comment: @sagarkodte when we float the element its require to clear the parent.

Comment: IMHO, if your non-clearfixed sections (them having 0 height) doesn't produce any unwanted collateral effects, then it's ok to let them this way. What's important here is to understand that this issue is all about _floating_ and it has nothing to do with the `section` tag itself or its semantics.

Comment: @JordiNebot Use the dev tools, there are no floating elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <section id="amenities-part" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
            <h2>Amenities</h2>
            <span>Lift</span> <br><span>AC</span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="services-part" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
            <h2>Services</h2>
            <span>Cooking</span> <br><span>Cooking</span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="safety-part" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
            <h2>Safety</h2>
            <span>First Aid Kit</span> <br><span>Fire Extinguisher </span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="local-service-part" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
            <h2>Local Area Service</h2>
            <span>jfh</span> <br><span>jfh</span>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="handler-detail-part" class="col-md-6">
        <div>
            <h2>Handler Detail</h2>
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="Handler-profile-picture" width="75px" src="https://www.primomedico.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Prof-Dr-Schmidli-Juerg-Spezialist-Gefaesschirurgie-Bern-Portrait_klein.jpg">
            <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

you  can also use this it simple

Answer (score 0):

The HTML  element represents a generic section of a document, i.e., a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading. Each  should be identified, typically by including a heading (- element) as a child of the  element.

**Here is a example:**

**Before**

```
<div>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <img src="bird.jpg" alt="bird">
</div>
```

**After**

```
<section>
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <img src="bird.jpg" alt="bird">
</section>
```